# Why is the Doctor still called "the last of his kind"?

Tags: doctor-who

Being the last of his kind is a huge part of Doctor Who's ego and a recurring trope in dark-mood-monologues. Yet every other series or so, we see the Master appearing, reappearing, turning female etc., or Gallifrey rendering houses to be in need of restoration.

Is there an in-world explanation why the Doctor considers himself the last of his kind nevertheless? (My question excludes the revelations of the Timeless Child, as it was unknown to the Doctor before.)

Comment: Doctor Who (2005) series starts with The Doctor's belief that The Doctor ended The Great Time War by killing ALL Time Lords as well as the Daleks. The Doctor quickly learned that a Dalek somehow survived. But, it wasn't until the end of season 3 until he learned that The Master had also survived. And even then, The Master died shortly by the end of season 3. Do you have citation from very recent episodes that he/she says himself/ herself *Last of The Time Lords*?

Comment: Even if Capaldi used the phrase Gallifrey was stuck in a pocket dimension with little chance of being found again and that was sure to take lots of effort.  Until they returned anticlimactically on their own.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, The Doctor has not referred to himself as the last of his kind since other Time Lords have been revealed to be alive. Have you got any quotes from series other than 1-5 when the Time Lords were thought to be dead?

Comment: The Twelfth Doctor introduced the Master/Mistress to Bill as **"the other Last of the Time Lords"**. Tongue in cheek, but says it all really.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the classic series, The Doctor visited Gallifrey or met with other Time Lords on a fairly routine basis. He was battling The Rani and The Master in both the final series of 'classic' Doctor Who as well as the 8th Doctor 'movie'.

The first time The Doctor ever said he was "the last of his kind" or specifically The Last Time Lord was at the beginning of the series' return in 2005. Russell T Davies created a story arc which began with the death of all the Time Lords at the hands of The Doctor in the Time War. However, the Time Lords were shown again before the end of RTD's time as showrunner, so evidently that was always part of his story arc. Steven Moffat's era saw them saved from the Time War and return, albeit sealed off in a 'bubble universe'.

To the best of my knowledge, The Doctor has not referred to himself as the last of his kind since other Time Lords have been revealed to be alive.

Additionally, it has been suggested that other 'rogue' Time Lords may still be roaming the universe and were not part of the Time War. In 'classic' Who there were a number of other Time Lords who had left Gallifrey, including 'The Monk' and K'anpo Rimpoche. Their current whereabouts are unknown, and The Doctor only assumed all other Timelords had been involved and died in the Time War. However, in *The Doctor's Wife*, The Doctor received a communication from another rogue, *The Corsair*, and went on to discover the remains of many other Time Lords who had been lured to the same planet, suggesting that others could have survived The Time War.